# How can a webservice find out the URL the client used to call this webmethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Suppose i have a webservice (http://myWebservice/CodeGenerator/CodeValidator.asmx) as follows

```
[WebMethod]
public string ValidateCode(string sCode)
{
    // I need to check requested url here. The call comes from different sites.
    // For example www.abc.com/accesscode.aspx. I need to get this url. 
}
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Tom, This is not the solution.I need to get CLIENT URL which is called the webservice method.